# I've got a riddle to put in the yard

Tags: riddle, word, metapuzzles

I've got a riddle to put in the yard.
Don't you all fret; it's really quite hard.
A question I hide in these lines of bad phrase.
Can you answer it and so just amaze?

Thirteen and five squared spell out the start.
Counting from A, if you are smart.

Right in the front, you'll find this place.
Only one man can win in a race.

You all know why we are here.
A challenge brings joy, not lots of fear.

A small little bug counts out the time.
It wants your blood or perhaps just a chime.

When words fall apart, they need a sleuth.
Reorder and Solve to find the truth.

The greatest question remains on this list.
Not where, what or when, of that I insist.

**That's all it is; six words I have lost.**
**If you found them all, they all point to _____.**

---

**Hint:**

> None of the lost words are in the lines.
>  You can all Solve it, just watch for the signs.

> After the third word, take a small break.
>  One word's a proper noun, but don't let your heart ache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F1Krazy has written up all partial solutions and the six words seem to say:

> My first puzzle: Tick loves whom?
>
>  "My first puzzle" refers to the OP's first puzzle here on PSE, [Web of Spirits – a puzzle of romance](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41819/web-of-spirits-a-puzzle-of-romance). This puzzle is about a romantic web and the eternal question of who loves whom.
>
>  This puzzle has a character named Tick, who, as Joe's answer reveals, pursues a character called Frost.

So the final answer is:

> That's all it is; six words I have lost.
>  If you found them all, they all point to **Frost**.

---

*Note*: This answer was completely rewritten after the OP commented. Look at the history if you must know what I first proposed in a very convoluted first draft.

Comment: You are much closer than you think. You have the correct last word, but for the wrong reason.

Comment: I know that my connection is rather laboured. The phrase "they all point to ---" makes me think that each of the words can be connected to frost individually, but I don't see how. (First frost? Tick/frost bite?)

Comment: That isn't the meaning of that phrase; it's just the best I could find that fit the pseudo-meter I had going. The six words form one question. Gareth has made a mistake that is leading you all off the path.

Comment: A-ha! So I'll go resaerch the Web some more ... `:)`

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer:

Thirteen and five squared spell out the start.
Counting from A, if you are smart.

> My (found by @Gareth McCaughan)

Right in the front, you'll find this place.
Only one man can win in a race.

> First

You all know why we are here.
A challenge brings joy, not lots of fear.

> Possibly "Puzzle" (found by @Techidiot)

A small little bug counts out the time.
It wants your blood or perhaps just a chime.

> Tick

When words fall apart, they need a sleuth.
Reorder and Solve to find the truth.

> Loves (an anagram of "Solve", as suggested by @M Oehm)

The greatest question remains on this list.
Not where, what or when, of that I insist.

> I'm thinking "Whom"

Altogether, this forms the question:

> "My first puzzle tick loves whom?"
>
>  According to the OP, his first puzzle tick went to a user named Joe, but that doesn't fit the rhyme scheme. So somewhere I've gone wrong slightly.

Comment: If we're posting partial answers, you can add MY for the first stanza. Presumably the third is something like PUZZLE, the fifth is something like ANAGRAM, and the sixth is WHO, WHY or HOW. But how we put those together to make something informative and rhyming with "lost", I don't see at present.

Comment: (The original poster's first puzzle is called "Web of Spirits - a puzzle of romance" and doesn't seem particularly helpful. S/he doesn't have any accepted answers, so we're not looking for "my first ... tick" in that sense.)

Comment: I wouldn't place any large bets on ANAGRAM being right. Might be some other variety of words-falling-apart. (If the "my first ..." thing indicates something to do with qwertyu63's puzzles, it may be worth noting that they haven't posted any questions with the anagram tag. First one with the cipher tag doesn't seem terribly enlightening here.)

Comment: Isn't the 3rd -> **Puzzle**? **MY FIRST PUZZLE TICK** _ _ ?

Comment: We're definitely getting closer...

Comment: Given that "Solve" has a capital S in the riddle and in the hint, the solution could be an anagram of Solve, probably Loves. "My first puzzle tick loves ---?"

Comment: You are very close. Words have more than one meaning. Also, the first answer I accepted was from a user by the name of Joe.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid being direct, but "tick" has nothing to do with the green check mark for accepted answers.

Comment: The OP's highest voted question is still in bounty question list! Its about sone alien message! Don't know whether this is related or not for last stanza.

Comment: @demonofthemist An interesting idea, but it will lead you astray. The number of votes my puzzles have do not effect the answer to this one (I considered that as a gimmick, but other peoples actions can trivially change the order. So I didn't.)

Comment: tbh at this point I'm just trying to think of words that rhyme with "lost" because I have no idea where else to go here. "Tossed"? "Frost"? "Compost"? ["Prost"?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_Prost)

Answer (score 0):

Another partial

You all know why we are here.
A challenge brings joy, not lots of fear.

> FUN?